# Best way to address SVN repository for portability

Tags: svn

We are in Windows environment

There are multiple ways addressing repository:

1) Via server computer name/FQDN (like svnerver.ourdomain.com)

2) Via IP address

3) Via an virtual host name in C:\Windows\System3​2\drivers\etc\hos​ts file (or I guess virtual host name could be setup in the router but we have people connecting to this repository via VPN from another office and our router doesn't do name resolution for them)

We have been using approach 3) with the host file and it proved to be convenient for portability - when our SVN server crashed I just took last backup, hosted it on another server, changed IP in my host file and I was back in business without having to do "svn relocate". This is especially convenient because we have people connecting to our repository remotely via VPN and all they had to do just change entry in their hosts file.

Now we are consolidating multiple repositories in one and I am reconsidering this approach. Are the any downsides to it?

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 is the best. What you are doing now requires everyone to update a hosts file for a new IP address. DNS is always a more seamless option when you are you trying to move hosts.